# flask function continuously instantiating class even in other routes

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application that looks like this:

```
import other_file

@app.route('/<hello>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def well(hello):
    print('created object!')
    class_object = MyClass(hello)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

other_file.py

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, bigvar):
        self.my_list = pd.df.loc[pd.df[bigvar] == 'something']
```

This class instantiates constantly no matter what route I'm on causing errors. Is there a better way to instantiate this class only once but access it in all my flask functions?

Comment: What you need is called a Singleton, which gets instantiated only once for the life of the program. There are many references online about that design pattern, here is the first one  Google gave me: https://python-patterns.guide/gang-of-four/singleton/

Comment: (And the simplest implementation for a Singleton is to have a module-global variable holding the expensive structure, and reusing it in your constructor each time you instantiate MyClass.)